# Unable to write to database error log4j2 JDBC appender with spring boot

Tags: postgresql, spring-boot, jdbc, log4j, log4j2

I want to write my log message to the specific table on the PostgreSQL database using log4j2.

but when I run the project it gives me the following error.

```
    2023-03-12 11:26:06,380 main ERROR Unable to write to database [JdbcManager{name=jdbcAppender, bufferSize=0, tableName=logs, columnConfigs=[{ name=date, layout=null, literal=null, timestamp=true }, { name=level, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=message, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=class, layout=%class, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[]}] for appender [jdbcAppender]. org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.DbAppenderLoggingException: Failed to insert record for log event in JDBC manager: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setNString(int, String) is not yet implemented. [columnConfigs=[{ name=date, layout=null, literal=null, timestamp=true }, { name=level, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=message, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=class, layout=%class, literal=null, timestamp=false }], sqlStatement=insert into logs (date,level,message,class) values (?,?,?,?), factoryData=FactoryData [connectionSource=factory{ public static java.sql.Connection com.pouya.logfix.LogsConfgi.getDatabaseConnection() }, tableName=logs, columnConfigs=[{ name=date, layout=null, literal=null, timestamp=true }, { name=level, layout=%level, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=message, layout=%message, literal=null, timestamp=false }, { name=class, layout=%class, literal=null, timestamp=false }], columnMappings=[], immediateFail=false, retry=true, reconnectIntervalMillis=5000, truncateStrings=true], connection=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5000/postgres, UserName=postgres, PostgreSQL JDBC Driver, statement=insert into logs (date,level,message,class) values ('2023-03-12 11:26:06.373+03:30',?,?,?), reconnector=null, isBatchSupported=true, columnMetaData={DATE=ColumnMetaData [schemaName=, catalogName=, tableName=logs, name=date, nameKey=DATE, label=date, displaySize=255, type=12, typeName=varchar, className=java.lang.String, precision=255, scale=0, isStringType=true], MESSAGE=ColumnMetaData [schemaName=, catalogName=, tableName=logs, name=message, nameKey=MESSAGE, label=message, displaySize=2147483647, type=12, typeName=text, className=java.lang.String, precision=2147483647, scale=0, isStringType=true], LEVEL=ColumnMetaData [schemaName=, catalogName=, tableName=logs, name=level, nameKey=LEVEL, label=level, displaySize=255, type=12, typeName=varchar, className=java.lang.String, precision=255, scale=0, isStringType=true], CLASS=ColumnMetaData [schemaName=, catalogName=, tableName=logs, name=class, nameKey=CLASS, label=class, displaySize=255, type=12, typeName=varchar, className=java.lang.String, precision=255, scale=0, isStringType=true]}]
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.writeInternal(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:871)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.writeThrough(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:898)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseManager.write(AbstractDatabaseManager.java:298)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.AbstractDatabaseAppender.append(AbstractDatabaseAppender.java:110)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.tryCallAppender(AppenderControl.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender0(AppenderControl.java:134)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppenderPreventRecursion(AppenderControl.java:125)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AppenderControl.callAppender(AppenderControl.java:89)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.callAppenders(LoggerConfig.java:675)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.processLogEvent(LoggerConfig.java:633)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:616)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.LoggerConfig.log(LoggerConfig.java:552)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.config.AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.log(AwaitCompletionReliabilityStrategy.java:82)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.Logger.log(Logger.java:161)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.tryLogMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2205)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageTrackRecursion(AbstractLogger.java:2159)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessageSafely(AbstractLogger.java:2142)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logMessage(AbstractLogger.java:2022)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.spi.AbstractLogger.logIfEnabled(AbstractLogger.java:1875)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.log(LogAdapter.java:266)
    at org.apache.commons.logging.LogAdapter$Log4jLog.debug(LogAdapter.java:240)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:213)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.registerBeanPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:270)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.registerBeanPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:762)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:567)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292)
    at com.pouya.logfix.LogfixApplication.main(LogfixApplication.java:26)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLFeatureNotSupportedException: Method org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setNString(int, String) is not yet implemented.
    at org.postgresql.Driver.notImplemented(Driver.java:731)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setNString(PgPreparedStatement.java:1522)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setNString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:238)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingPreparedStatement.setNString(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:238)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.appender.db.jdbc.JdbcDatabaseManager.writeInternal(JdbcDatabaseManager.java:850)
    ... 33 more
```

And somehow it is stuck in a loop because this message is printing over and over again in my console.

I'm using the **`ConnectionFactory`** to connect to the database.

Here is my **`log4j2-spring.xml`** file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration>
    <Appenders>
        <Console name="STDOUT" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <PatternLayout pattern="%m%n"/>
        </Console>

        <JDBC name="jdbcAppender" tableName="logs">
            <ConnectionFactory class="com.pouya.logfix.LogsConfig" method="getDatabaseConnection"/>
            <Column name="date" isEventTimestamp="true"/>
            <Column name="level" pattern="%level"/>
            <Column name="message" pattern="%message"/>
            <Column name="class" pattern="%class"/>
        </JDBC>
    </Appenders>
    <Loggers>
        <Root level="debug">
            <!--<AppenderRef ref="databaseAppender"/>-->
            <AppenderRef ref="STDOUT"/>
            <AppenderRef ref="jdbcAppender"/>
        </Root>
    </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

And here is the **`LogsConfig`** class:

```
    public class LogsConfgi {
        

        private static interface Singleton {
                final LogsConfgi INSTANCE = new LogsConfgi();
        }

        private final DataSource dataSource;

        private LogsConfgi() {
                
                try {
                        Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        System.exit(0);
                }

                Properties properties = new Properties();
                properties.setProperty("user", "postgres");
                properties.setProperty("password", "password");

                GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection> pool = new GenericObjectPool<PoolableConnection>();
                DriverManagerConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new DriverManagerConnectionFactory(
                        "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5000/postgres", properties
                );
                new PoolableConnectionFactory(connectionFactory, pool, null, "SELECT 1", 3, false, false, Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED);
                this.dataSource = new PoolingDataSource(pool);
        }

        public static Connection getDatabaseConnection() throws SQLException {
                var dt = Singleton.INSTANCE.dataSource.getConnection();
                return dt;
        }
  }
```

**I'm using spring boot version 2.7.9 and PostgreSQL driver version 42.5.4**.

Comment: Seems like a bug in the postgre driver. It crashes on trying to setNString which should be supported